# wait for one thread out of multiple running threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am starting multiple threads and the idea is to wait for only one of them(does not matter which one) to continue the main thread and ignoring the other threads. In other words the main thread starts several threads and then waits until the fastest thread joins. Any ideas how to implement such a thing?

Comment: You can use an ExecutorService and use the Futures to check if any tasks are done.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html There is also the method, "executeAny" which might be what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

There's several possibilities.

**1. Use a CountDownLatch**

The idea is to have a `CountDownLatch` set to `1`. All tasks running on the relevant threads will end by calling `countDown()` on it.
The main thread will simply call `await()` on it, and as soon as the first task is finished, the latch will hit 0, and release the waiting main thread.
This approach works with raw `Thread`s, as well as with an `ExecutorService`.

```
public class UseCountDownLatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numberOfThreads = 5;
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
            int print = i;
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(print * 3);
                    System.out.println(print);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } finally {
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                }
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();

        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Continue");

        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

**2. Use a CompletionService**

Wrap your `ExecutionService` in a `CompletionService`, then just wait for the first result to come in, and ignore further results.

```
public class UseCompletionService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numberOfThreads = 5;

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
        CompletionService<Void> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Void>(executorService);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
            int print = i;
            completionService.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(print * 3);
                    System.out.println(print);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                return null;
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();

        try {
            completionService.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Continue");

        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

**3. Use CompletableFutures**

The CompletableFutures API is made to make tasks composable. The trick is simply to combine the CompletableFutures for each individual task in a CompletableFuture that completes as soon as any of its components completes. Then it's just a matter of getting the result from the composed CompletableFuture.

```
public class UseCompletableFuture {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int numberOfThreads = 5;

        CompletableFuture<?>[] tasks = new CompletableFuture<?>[numberOfThreads];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
            int print = i;
            tasks[i] = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(print*3);
                    System.out.println(print);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            });
        }

        try {
            CompletableFuture.anyOf(tasks).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Continue");

        try {
            CompletableFuture.allOf(tasks).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```